# Eclipse Kepler And DataBase

Tags: java, database, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

Please somebody tell me how to install and connect a Database with Eclipse-Kepler. I did a try with Apache Derby.But it shows Error. I am a newbie in Programming,so please help.

[image: Right Click -Data Source Explorer]

[image: SelectedDB2 For windows]
[image: Set Username and Password And "FINISH"]

[image: ERROR Shows As in the Image]

Comment: what you are trying to do...?

Comment: i want to develop a Java Database Application Using Eclipse Kepler

Comment: Download the jdbc driver, and copy the jar file in your projects jar...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `database server` is up and running.
When you run your kepler `eclipse` switch to `Database Development perspective` and follow the steps mentioned [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.doc.user%2Fdoc%2Fhtml%2Fasc1229700344899.html) . Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1.Download Derby Plugin for Eclipse

2.Get the Derby Plugin for Eclipse (derby_core_plugin_10.2.2.zip and derby_ui_plugin_1.1.0.zip) From here http://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.2.2.0.html

3.Unzip the "derby_core_plugin_10.2.2.485682" files into the Eclipse home directory

4.There are two folders inside "derby_ui_plugin_1.1.0",which are "org.apache.derby.plugin.doc_1.1.0" and "org.apache.derby.ui_1.1.0". Copy these two folders inside the "Plugin" Folder which is located inside the Eclipse home directory.

5.Make sure there are these three folders inside ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins directory

- org.apache.derby.core_10.3.1
- org.apache.derby.ui_1.1.1
- org.apache.derby.plugin.doc_1.1.1

6.Open Eclipse

1. Select Window > Preferences from the main menu bar.
2. Expand Data Management > Connectivity and select Driver Definitions
3. Click Add.
4. In the Name/Type tab, indicate the version of Derby on which you want to create the driver definition.

   - Select Derby for the Vendor Filter to narrow the display to only Derby driver definitions
   - Select Derby Embedded JDBC Driver for the version of Derby you have installed.
   - (Optional) Modify the Driver Name if a driver definition with this name already exists

5.In the JAR List tab, highlight the default derby.jar file and click Edit JAR/Zip to indicate the fully qualified path of the Derby JAR file.

- Browse to the location of the ZIP file.
- Click Open

6.(Optional) In the Properties tab, modify the default properties for the driver definition template.

7.Click OK.

Now just restart the Eclipse and create your new DB Project and Right click on the Project folder -You can see the Apache listing there!!!